# HTML5: manipulate 16bit tiff images

Tags: javascript, image-processing, html5-canvas

I have some 16bit tiff images in my website. I would like to give the user the possibility to change the contrast curve (the astronomy experts refer to this process as stretching) to finally display a 8-bit-per-channel picture. I would like to use a few sliders as user interface. Is it even possible in HTML5? A JavaScript solution would be appreciated as well.

Comment: WebGL2.0 can handle many image format. GL_RGBA16UI, GL_RGBA16I  with 4 channel 16 bits per channel unsigned and signed shorts However you will have to locate a tiff decoder or write one yourself. Tiff can save images without compression so decoding should be simple if the tiffs are saved without compression. Load the pixels to a typed array and then create a webGL texture from that array and you can then view it in the browser (browser view is at 8 bits per channel I believe)

Comment: Is there an easier way to send the 16bit pixel values from my web server to the array in the browser than using tiff files (and find a way to decode them)?

Comment: If you have the raw pixel data you can save it to a file and the browser can read that file straight into a typed array https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data . you can define a custom mime type on the server and give the file a custom extension, eg *.tga and mine `image/x-tga` . When you create the file you don't need to follow the format, just add two 16 bit integers at the start to specify the width and height followed by a raw dump of the pixel data. Note the file will be large so make sure the server sends them compressed

Comment: Thanks, easier but inefficient... Somewhere else I've read about the idea to build two separate png files to send the first and the last 8 bit of each pixel. Then extract the data and produce the final 8 bit image to display according to the user's input. Sounds more efficient, even if definitely non-standard...

Comment: `somewhere else[...]`. I believe this was [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6413744/looking-to-access-16-bit-image-data-in-javascript-webgl).