# How to load 16 bits grayscale png in OpenCV.js?

Tags: javascript, opencv

I want to load a 16 bit grayscale PNG in Javascript (where each pixel represent a number/depth value. [This is file format is used by TUM to store depth information](https://vision.in.tum.de/data/datasets/rgbd-dataset/file_formats))

However, the image read by opencv.js is RGBA 8bits (`mat.type() == 24 == cv.CV_8UC4` - and I would like to get `cv.CV_16UC1`), which seems to be because the image is decode by the browser itself and `Because canvas only support 8-bit RGBA image with continuous storage, the cv.Mat type is cv.CV_8UC4` as the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/master/df/d24/tutorial_js_image_display.html) indicates it. Thus instead of getting a pixel we a value between 0 and 65535 (2^8-1) I get a number between 0 and 255 (2^8-1) with R=G=B and A=255

[Edit] To reformulate it, canvas convert my 16bit grayscale to 8bit RGBA. Canvas handle 2^24 colors but as during the conversion R=G=B and each channel is 2^8, thus it handle only 2^8 grays instead of 2^16 grays.

Nothing special is done :
https://jsfiddle.net/remmel/rmntq4yb/74/

Extract:

```js
var img = await loadImage("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/remmel/rgbd-dataset/main/rgbd_dataset_freiburg1_desk/depth/1305031468.188327.png");
var canvasOriginal = document.getElementById('canvas0')
var ctxOriginal = canvasOriginal.getContext('2d')
canvasOriginal.width = img.width
canvasOriginal.height = img.height
ctxOriginal.drawImage(img, 0, 0)
var mat = cv.imread('canvas0')
console.log(mat.channels(), mat.type() === cv.CV_8UC4) //4, true
```

Image magick:

```
$ identify 1305031468.188327.png
1305031468.188327.png PNG 640x480 640x480+0+0 16-bit Grayscale Gray 131604B 0.000u 0:00.000
```

I tried to decoded the image using jimp-browser, but still get a RGBA image. Debugging it, I see that it read the correct gray value in 16bit but after convert it in 8bit with R=G=B=gray 8bit and A=255. A solution could be to custom [(fix?)](https://github.com/oliver-moran/jimp/issues/988) that lib

I also tried loading directly the image with OpenCV.js, but still the same 4 channels image :

`<img src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/8am9t.png' id='dpng' />`

```
  var depthMat2 = cv.imread('dpng')
  console.log(depthMat2.channels(), depthMat2.type() === cv.CV_8UC4) //4 true
```

Image (imgur seems to not compress the image) :
[image]

Comment: I'm don't understand the question. canvas supports 16,777,216 colors. What is your actual goal?

Comment: Yes, canvas support 2^24 *colors*. But it seems to support only 256 grays. Canvas convert the 16 bits grayscale image to 8 bits RGBA

Comment: There are 256 actual greys because gray is when all of the colors of the RGB spectrum are the same. R = 0, G = 0, B = 0; R = 1, G = 1, B = 1; all the way to R = 255, G = 255, B = 255.

Comment: Yes, but my original image as grays between 0 and 65535. And Canvas doesn't handle R=65535, G=65535, B=65535 (I made an edit, if it helps)

Comment: Canvas `ctx.drawImage(imageElement)` should just work automatically, as long as that imageElement is loaded and is a `.png`. I still don't understand your goal. What is it?

Comment: I want to read a gray value between 0-65535 and I need that precision. But canvas convert it  dividing it by 256 and provides me a value between 0-255. In that image the value 1 represent 0.2mm. And the PNG file is correct as I successfull read it in java and c++

Comment: Do the responses to this StackOverflow question from back in 2011 offer any help? The leading answer suggests that it might be possible using a WebGL canvas - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6413744/looking-to-access-16-bit-image-data-in-javascript-webgl

Comment: Have you solved this issue? I am stuck with the same thing

Comment: @PaulBrink yes, see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used instead `fast-png` lib to read my 16 bits grayscale PNG : https://www.npmjs.com/package/fast-png

```
import { decode } from 'fast-png'
...
var arrayBuffer = await((await fetch(urlDepth)).arrayBuffer())
var depthData = (await decode(arrayBuffer)).data
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you just want to do ratio math:

```js
function rgbAlter(rgb){
  return 65535/255*rgb;
}
for(let i=0,l=256; i<l; i++){
  console.log(rgbAlter(i));
}
```

Comment: To give you a concreate example, in that png the 3rd  pixel is gray(8213) but the browser gives me for that 3rd pixel rgba(32,32,32,255) and 8213/256=32.08 (another example 4th pixel: gray(8841) rgba(34,34,34,255), 8841>>8=34). As you see if you lose information, you can not get it back : 32*256 = 8192 != 8213